# how to implement the folder lock in java

Tags: java, file-io, nio, file-locking

i want lock the particular folder, and i have code but the "java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Access is denied)" error is found

```
public class Folder_Lock {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    FileLock lock = null;
    FileChannel channel = null;
        try {
            // Get a file channel for the file

            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\kaizen\\Desktop\\mani1");

            channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();

            // Use the file channel to create a lock on the file.
            // This method blocks until it can retrieve the lock.
            lock = channel.lock();

            // Try acquiring the lock without blocking. This method returns
            // null or throws an exception if the file is already locked.
            try {

                lock = channel.tryLock();

            } catch (OverlappingFileLockException e) {

                // File is already locked in this thread or virtual machine
            }

            // Release the lock


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (lock!=null) try { lock.release(); } catch (IOException e) { }
            // Close the file
            if (channel!=null) try { channel.close(); } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

    }
}
```

can any one solve the issue

Comment: I'd take this more seriously if it didn't have `catch (Exception e) {}` at the end.

Comment: Is mani1 a file ?
If yes, do you have write access to it ?
The exact stack trace would be useful...
To answer the last question, I would suggest to print some information about e ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an exception Handler to handle the exception. In

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\kaizen\\Desktop\\mani1.addExtension");
```

This will resolve your issue.

Comment: Adding extension will not resolve user's issue.User is ttrying to set lock on directory level which is not possible with the code he has written.User is trying to acquire of dir possibly and hence failing.

Answer (score 0):

try running your folder throught admin or First Run IDE as admin and the run the file
since ur in C:/ system access permission is needed